# Php5 install conf.d folder missing

Tags: php

I've been trying to install php5 on my ubuntu server, but I'm running into a problem. The `conf.d` folder doesn't exist within `/etc/php5` how can I obtain that folder?

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/php5/conf.d/` is created when you install certain extensions like mysqli, mcrypt, pdo, curl, etc. I don't believe the directory is included as part of a fresh php5 install through Ubuntu's aptitude.

Until then, configuration files can be found in `/etc/php5/apache2/` (for execution in apache) and `/etc/php5/cli/` (for executing PHP from the command line).